# Get row with max value from each group based on multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, group-by

Let's say I have the following table STUDENTMARKS:

Table

[image]

Where Name+Age+ID together represents one individual person. I want to get the the rows where each student gets the highest score in shortest amount of time. First we will give priority to score and if any student has same score then we will take the shortest time taken and we can say the time will be unique. Basically I want the following output:

Output

[image]

I tried this following sql but it doesn't work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM STUDENTMARKS GROUP BY Name, Age, ID ORDER BY Score DESC, Time ASC
```

Any recommendations?

Comment: Student AAA has 2 time 55 & 52 with highest score 95. How you pick 52 from them? is there any other ordering column available?

Comment: @R_R if the score is same then we will go with the record that has shorter time. As Student AAA has 2 time 55 & 52 with highest score 95, we took the lower one which is 52. Answer posted below served the purpose. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`

```
select * from
(
select *,row_number() over(partition by name, age, id order by score desc, time asc) as rn
from STUDENTMARKS
)A where rn=1
```

Comment: @AnOrdinaryProgrammer, happy to know that it helped u. Please don't forget to mark it as accepted answer :)